# Maven - Create custom war depending parameters value

Tags: java, maven, continuous-integration

I have a maven war project, and I want to have create from the project 2 differents .war when I package it.

What I want to do it is to exclude and provide a different name depending from a parameters value. I want to delete and provide a different name to the .war.

This is the current structure:

[image]

For example:

I want to create an alternative war using the command:

mvn package -Psystem=SystemB

This is going to exclude somefoldes. for example, it will delete the folder 'manager' (marked in the image) in the new war.

This should generate in target/another-war.war (without the 'manager' foder)

Answer (score 0):

I think you could achieve that by using maven profiles (as you are suggesting) on your question and by using [packagingExcludes](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/including-excluding-files-from-war.html) option from maven war plugin. You can have several different profile configurations each one containing a different configuration for the maven plugin where you can use the packagingExcludes option to exclude the folders you want.

P.S. Maven profiles are used without equal sign, like :
 mvn -Pprofile1 profile2